# Trigger event on certain time or button pressed

Tags: python, datetime, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a python script for my Raspberry Pi for opening the door of my chicken coop at a certain time of day and and to be able to control it via buttons. It already works, but I'm not yet completely satisfied with the solution.

```
    while True:
        if current_Time > openDoorTime && currentTime < closeDoorTime:
            openDoor()
        if currentTime > closeDoorTime && currentTime < openDoorTime:
            closeDoor()

        if openDoorButton is pressed:
            openDoor()
        if closeDoorButton is pressed:
            closeDoor()
```

Is there a more elegant solution to listen to clock times and pressed buttons at the same time?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is like math.

**openDoorTime** is lower than **current_Time** and **current_Time** is lower than **closeDoorTime**, so **open_door_time** < **current_time** < **close_door_time**.

And you have to use ***and***, ***or*** operants. And I recomended to use underscores when naming variables. Use **open_door_time** instead of **openDoorTime**.

```py
while True:
    if open_door_time < current_time < close_door_time or open_door_button is pressed:
        open_door()
    if close_door_time < current_time < open_door_time or close_door_button is pressed:
        close_door()
```